# How to make "n" level folder tree by mkdir -p or bat script on windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mkdir

As you may know, md -p can create a tree folder like:
mkdir -p

but how to create a "n" deep folder by script such as bat or any other?

Directory tree sample:
 - C:\
 -- 001
 --- 002
 ---- 003
 ..............
 ----- n

Thanks anyway
Rover

Comment: How do you know what you're going to call the subdirectories? Or is it literally going to be 001/002/003/etc?

Comment: cmd's `mkdir` / `md` command is already equivalent to Unix `mkdir -p`. There is no '-p' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
 ( for /l %a in (1 1 10) do md %a & cd %a ) & cd "%cd%"
```

To be used from command line. To use it inside a batch file, percent signs need to be escaped, replacing `%a` with `%%a`

For a padded version you can use

```dos
cmd /v /c "for /l %a in (1001 1 1005) do (set "x=%a" & md !x:~-3! & cd !x:~-3!)"
```

Comment: Thank you MC ND ! you are the answer!

Comment: According to your explanation, my understanding is : 
[For bat]
for /l %%a in (1 1 10) do md %%a & cd %%a & cd "%cd%"

Comment: @SkyRover, the parenthesis in the code are needed. The last `cd "%cd%"` (that simply return to the starting point) should be executed when the `for` has ended creating the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

This script will create 999 folders inside each other (from 001 to 999):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,999) DO (
    IF %%i LSS 10 (
        MD 00%%i
        CD 00%%i
    ) ELSE (
        IF %%i LSS 100 (
            MD 0%%i
            CD 0%%i
        ) ELSE (
            MD %%i
            CD %%i
        )
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Or in this simpler way: `for /L %%i in (1001,1,1999) do (set i=%%i & md !i:~1! & cd !i:~1!)`, but the resulting folders will probably exceed the maximum length for a name supported by Windows.

Comment: Thank you MichaelS ! you are the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If Command Extensions are enabled (the default) then `MD` command will create all intermediate directories in the given path if they don't exists, so you just need to enter something like this:

```
md C:\001\002\003
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini, I know md could make all directories, but waste time if I need to create 100 level just by typing in hand.....